# ACS - Google OpenID Connect Migration - NameIdentifier changed

Tags: acs, azure-acs

we migrated our ACS Namespaces to Google OpenID Connect, according to the guidance:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn927169.aspx

Unfortunately the NameIdentifier claim from Google changes after the migration, so we cannot map the existing users to the new identifier (subject); also our custom mapping to other resources inside the application breaks with this behavior.

In the migration guide it is explicitly stated, that this should not be the case.

Any hints? Thank you in advance...

Btw: According the guidance i should tag this post with 'acs-google', but this tag does not exisit yet, and i do not have the required reputation, to create a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

We contacted Microsoft support, the problem could be reproduced, and now it is fixed.